# Keep fragment in URL when redirecting from controller

Tags: laravel-8, inertiajs, php-8

When redirecting from the controller, after an action like store (POST http request):

```
class EntityController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        ....
        return redirect()->route('entities.list')->withFragment('manage');
    }
}
```

How can I keep the hash in the URL?

For instance, in the case above, return to the page `https://example.com/entities#manage`

I am suspecting that Inertia is doing some magic behind in this case, because I am not being able to keep the hash in the URL. From what it is written in Laravel docs, it seems that it should be possible.

Relevant tech stack:

- **Laravel Framework**: 8.42.1
- **inertiajs/inertia-laravel**: v0.3.6

References:

- [Inertia - Redirects](https://inertiajs.com/redirects)
- [Laravel @ GitHub - RedirectResponse class, withFragment method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php)

Comment: I've wrote the solution I found for this problem in [github](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/issues/85#issuecomment-1183029451)

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, as mentioned in the Github issue I asked in the [Inertia Discord](https://discord.com/invite/inertiajs) channel if there is a solution for this. Robert Boes gave me the following answer.

> I don't think that'll ever work, because the request is made using
> XHR. So the browser will deal with the redirect.
>
> Quickly tried it in PingCRM, the response is a 302 with the following
> header: Location: http://pingcrm.test/contacts#something so the
> correct redirect URL is set. However, the followup request is made by
> the browser which is just GET http://pingcrm.test/contacts. So the
> browser will discard the fragment, afaik this isn't something Inertia
> can do anything about. Even the underlying library has no impact
> (Axios), because the browser itself will do the redirect, not Axios.
>
> XHR requests are always made without a fragment, as seen here:
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL
> any URL fragment present in the URL will be stripped away.
>
> Can't find the RFC that that has all this explained right now, but
> iirc it's just how these requests work. For example, if you do
> Inertia::get('/dashboard#something') then Inertia will strip the
> fragment from the URL, make the request and after the request is
> completed it will add the fragment back to the URL using the History
> API, because the fragment is not sent along with the XHR request.

Answer (score 0):

You should first create the URL, using named route.

```
$url = URL::route('route_name', ['#hash_tag']);

Redirect::to($url);
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: I already saw the community suggesting that approach in several foruns but I do not agree with it. That would generate an URL like https://example.com/route?#hash_tag and it is better that it does not include the question mark. I think that an approach like `$url = URL::route('route_name') . '#hash_tag';` is better. BUT, I already tried them and _both doesn't work_ also.

Comment: You can use the `redirect('some-url')->withFragment('hash_tag')` method to add a fragment to a redirect.

Comment: @erikgaal that is the same approach that I am explaining it doesn`t work. Are you using the same stack, Laravel and Inertia?

Comment: Also have this issue only when using Inertia.  `return to_route('myroute')->withFragment('someanchor');` omits the fragment.